# What does this Angular error mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm trying to upgrade my app from Angular v2 to v4, and I'm using AOT compilation. Can anyone explain how to resolve this error, which doesn't identify any of my own code (only Angular's).

`Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in /project/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol ɵf in /project/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol ɵf in /project/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts`

I'm aware about not using lambdas etc, and my code was compiling fine in v2, so I assume that isn't the problem.

Comment: add the code to see which is causing this issue.

Comment: Probably related to AOT. Check these do's and don'ts https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#aot-dos-and-donts

Comment: Yes I suspect it is AOT related. I assume the dos and don'ts are the same for Angular 2 as well though, and that worked fine. I can't paste my whole app and the error gives no indication of what part is causing it.

Comment: It's usually a function call or inline closure within an `@NgModule(...)` or `@Component(...)` decorator, or code referenced from there.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. It seems pretty silly that it can't identify what file is causing it though. If anything, surely these error messages need to be upgraded.

Comment: Sure, create a feature request (if none exists yet)

Answer (score 0):

Try with reinstalling the **ngc**.

```
$ npm install ngc
```